# Custom checkbox design

Tags: html, css

I need to make custom design for checkbox. So there is 3 states:

1. disabled: `border: 1px solid #EDEEF0; border-radius: 2px; box-sizing: border-box;`
2. hover/active: `border: 1px solid #E0431E; border-radius: 2px; box-sizing: border-box;`
3. Checked: `border: 1px solid #E0431E; border-radius: 2px; box-sizing: border-box;` + custom check mark which i did by .svg.

My problem is -  i can't insert an .svg icon with a changing border of a checkbox. Changes or checkmark or border.
How can i solve this? How can i add border and chek mark either?

```css
#check{
        display: none;
}

.hiddenSpan{
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #EDEEF0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;

}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .hiddenSpan:before{
    content:url(checkmark.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<label for="check" id="checkLabel">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="input__section__footer-checkbox" required>
                            <span class="hiddenSpan"></span></label>
```

Comment: You could use font awesome

Comment: maybe z-index command should help?

Comment: [Here is](https://codepen.io/aruizh/pen/LgqxzJ) a custom checkbox that I usually use. May be it could help you.

Comment: I would use background css property instead of content.